# Reading Excel file from Azure Databricks

Tags: python-3.x, excel, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

Am trying to ready Excel file (`.xlsx`) from Azure Databricks, file is in ADLS Gen 2.

Example:

```
srcPathforParquet = "wasbs://hyxxxx@xxxxdatalakedev.blob.core.windows.net//1_Raw//abc.parquet"
srcPathforExcel = "wasbs://hyxxxx@xxxxdatalakedev.blob.core.windows.net//1_Raw//src.xlsx"
```

Reading parquet file from the path works fine.

```
srcparquetDF = spark.read.parquet(srcPathforParquet )
```

Reading excel file from the path throw error: **No such file or directory**

```
srcexcelDF = pd.read_excel(srcPathforExcel , keep_default_na=False, na_values=[''])
```

Comment: Is that you use pandas to read excel file?

Comment: @JimXu : Yes using Pandas

Comment: According to the document, `pandas.read_excel` does not support   `wasbs`  scheme : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method  `pandas.read_excel`  does not support using `wasbs` or `abfss` scheme URL to access the file. For more details, please refer to [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

So if you want to access the file with pandas, I suggest you create a sas token and use `https` scheme with sas token to access the file or download the file as stream then read it with pandas. Meanwhile, you also mount the storage account as filesystem then access file as  @CHEEKATLAPRADEEP-MSFT said.

For example

- Access with sas token

1. create sas token via Azure portal
   [image]
2. Code

```
pdf=pd.read_excel('https://<account name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<file system>/<path>?<sas token>')
print(pdf)
```

[image]

- Download the file as stream and read the file

1. Install package `azure-storage-file-datalake` and `xlrd` with pip in databricks
2. Code

```
import io

import pandas as pd
from azure.storage.filedatalake import BlobServiceClient
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient

blob_service_client = DataLakeServiceClient(account_url='https://<account name>.dfs.core.windows.net/', credential='<account key>')

file_client = blob_service_client.get_file_client(file_system='test', file_path='data/sample.xlsx')
with io.BytesIO() as f:
  downloader =file_client.download_file()
  b=downloader.readinto(f)
  print(b)
  df=pd.read_excel(f)
  print(df)
```

[image]

Besides we also can use pyspark to read excel file. But we need to add jar `com.crealytics:spark-excel` in our environment. For more details, please refer to [here](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/18295/how-to-read-excel-file-using-databricks.html) and [here](https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel)

For example

1. Add package `com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.1` via maven. Besides, **please note that if you use scala 2.11, please add package `com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.11:0.13.1`**
2. Code

```
spark._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.azure.account.key.<account name>.dfs.core.windows.net",'<account key>')

print("use spark")
df=sqlContext.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
        .option("header", "true") \
        .load('abfss://test@testadls05.dfs.core.windows.net/data/sample.xlsx')

df.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As per my repro, reading excel file from ADLS gen2 cannot accessed directly using the storage account access key. When I tried reading excel file via ADLS gen2 URL, I got the same error message as `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abfss://filesystem@chepragen2.dfs.core.windows.net/flightdata/drivers.xlsx'`.

[image]

**Steps to read Excel file (`.xlsx`) from Azure Databricks, file is in ADLS Gen 2:**

**Step1:** Mount the ADLS Gen2 storage account.

```
configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type": "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<application-id>",
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope-name>",key="<service-credential-key-name>"),
           "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token"}

# Optionally, you can add <directory-name> to the source URI of your mount point.
dbutils.fs.mount(
  source = "abfss://<file-system-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/",
  mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = configs)
```

**Step2:** Read excel file using the mount path.

[image]

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks - Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/azure/azure-datalake-gen2)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the following are the basic steps that worked for me in reading the excel file from ADLS2 in the databricks :

- **Installed the following library on my Databricks cluster**.

> com.crealytics:spark-excel_2.12:0.13.6

- **Added the below spark configuration**.

> spark.conf.set(adlsAccountKeyName,adlsAccountKeyValue)

adlsAccountKeyName --> fs.azure.account.key.YOUR_ADLS_ACCOUNT_NAME>.blob.core.windows.net
adlsAccountKeyValue --> sas key of your adls account

- **Used the below code to get the spark dataframe out of my excel file in ADLS**.

> ```
> myDataFrame = (spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
>             .option("dataAddress", "'Sheetname'!")
>           .option("header", "true")
>           .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "true")
>           .option("inferSchema", "false") 
>           .option("addColorColumns", "false") 
>           .option("startColumn", 0) 
>           .option("endColumn", 99)  
>           .option("timestampFormat", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss")
>           .load(FullFilePathExcel)
>           )
> ```